# Why is my slice from redux-toolkit boolean toggle action not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to hide or show a Dropdown box based on a boolean placed on a onClick. Here is the code, divided in three parts, the slice, the useSelector and useDispatch, and the onClick element.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'cart',
    initialState:{value:{hidden:true}},
    reducers:{
        show: (state,action) =>{
           return !state.hidden
    }

}

})

export default cartSlice.reducer

export const {show} = cartSlice.actions
```

Second Part

```
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import { show } from '../../redux/features/cartSlice';
 const dispatch = useDispatch()

 const hidden = useSelector(state => state.cart.value)
```

onClick and dynamic render

```
 <CartIcon onclick={()=>{dispatch(show())}} />
            {console.log(hidden)}
            </div>
            {!hidden? <div>
            < CartDropdown  />
            </div> : null}
         <div>
          </div>
```

Comment: you missed .value inbetween     show: (state,action) =>{
           return !state.value.hidden

Answer (score 2):

Because your initial state is:

```js
initialState: {
  value: {
    hidden: true
  }
}
```

Your reducer should match it accordingly (note, you don't need to return anything with Redux toolkit as it uses immer under the hood. Immer will return a finalised version of state for you):

```js
show: (state, action) => {
  state.value.hidden = !state.value.hidden;
}
```

I'd also need to see your store, to see what you've called your cart reducer, but I think your selector should be:

```
const hidden = useSelector(state => state.cart.value.hidden)
```

or you could destructure it like so:

```
const { hidden } = useSelector(state => state.cart.value)
```

Comment: Made the changes u said but it's still not working though.. here is the store:                       
 `import cartReducer from './redux/features/cartSlice'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer:{
    cart: cartReducer
  }
})`

Comment: What error message are you getting?